# JSON created by mySQL query return undefined but array is the same

Tags: php, mysql, json

Working on a mySql, PHP, jquery web app.

I am now at the point where my jQuery script works fine with data retrieved from a .php script, but when I get that data in the .php script from my mySQL Database I get undefined for the values on my page out on data that came from the db.

Here is the php.

```
 $get_par ="SELECT  hole, par FROM course_card cc
 LEFT JOIN tour_event_rounds ter ON ter.course_id = cc.course_id
 WHERE tour_id='$tid' AND rnd='$rnd' limit 9";
 $gp_res = mysql_query($get_par) or die(mysql_error());
 $golfer_id=25;
 $score_arr[$golfer_id]["name"]="Bob Golfer";
  while ($array = mysql_fetch_array($gp_res)) {
    $hole = $array['hole']+0;
    $score_arr[$golfer_id]["$hole"] = $array['par']+0;
  }

$golfer_id=45;
$score_arr[$golfer_id]["name"]="Joe Golfer";
$score_arr[$golfer_id][1]=4;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][2]=3;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][3]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][4]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][5]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][6]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][7]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][8]=5;
$score_arr[$golfer_id][9]=5;

echo json_encode($score_arr);
```

The encoded JSON array from the above php script outputs this

```
{"25":
     {"name":"Bob Golfer","1":4,"2":3,"3":4,"4":5,"5":4,"6":5,"7":4,"8":4,"9":3},
 "45":
     {"name":"Joe Golfer","1":4,"2":3,"3":5,"4":5,"5":5,"6":5,"7":5,"8":5,"9":5}
 }
```

As you can see the data hole data for Bob is identical to Joe in the JSON array.

But when I run my js jQuery script.  Bob's data is undefined yet joe's is fine.
How can this be??

here is the js

```
<?php
$hole=1;
$grp=$_REQUEST['grp'];
$tid=$_REQUEST['tid'];
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

tid= <?php echo "$tid"; ?>+0;
grp= <?php echo "$grp"; ?>+0;
rnd= <?php echo "$rnd"; ?>+0;

hole = <?php echo "$hole"; ?>+0;
gid=25;
var score_arr  ;
var total = new Array() ;
var total_f = new Array() ;
var total_b = new Array() ;

$(document).ready(function(){

// SET the intial values
$("#hole_num").text(hole);

// Get Data from db
 $.getJSON("gse_db_int.php",{"tid":tid,"grp":grp,"rnd":rnd}, function(data){
 console.log(data); //uncomment this for debug


$("#score").text(data[gid][hole]);
$("#golfer_name").text(data[gid]["name"]);
score_arr= data;

}); //End json

// show the right view
  $("table#one_nine").show();
  $("table#ten_plus").hide();
  $("table#score_entry").show();
  $("table#score_summary").hide();




$("#next_hole").click(function(){
  hole=hole+1;
$("#hole_num").text(hole);
$("#score").text(score_arr[gid][hole]);
$("#golfer_name").text(score_arr[gid]["name"]);
});

$("#prev_hole").click(function(){
  hole=hole-1;
$("#hole_num").text(hole);
$("#score").text(score_arr[gid][hole]);
});

$(".score_button").click(function() {
score_arr[gid][hole]= parseInt(this.value);
$("#score").text(score_arr[gid][hole]);
    });

$("#but_ten_plus").click(function() {
      $("table#one_nine").hide();
      $("table#ten_plus").show();
    });
 $("#but_one_nine").click(function() {
      $("table#one_nine").show();
      $("table#ten_plus").hide();
    });

 $("table#tab_head").click(function() {
     score_summary();
      $("table#score_entry").hide();
      $("table#score_summary").show();

 });
 $("tr#sum_head").click(function() {
      $("table#score_entry").show();
      $("table#score_summary").hide();
 });

// build the score summary
function score_summary(){
    $("#plug").text("");
 $.each(score_arr,function(gid,i){
    console.log(gid);
    console.log(score_arr[gid]["name"]);
    total[gid]=0;
    total_f[gid]=0;
    total_b[gid]=0;
    $("#plug").append('<td> '+score_arr[gid]["name"]+' </td> ');
 //FRONT
    for(hol=1; hol <= 9 ; hol++){
        $("#plug").append('<td> '+score_arr[gid][hol]+' </td> ');
        console.log(score_arr[gid][hol]);
      total_f[gid]= total_f[gid]+ score_arr[gid][hol];
    }
    $("#plug").append('<td> '+total_f[gid]+' </td> ');

//BACK
      for(hol=1; hol <= 9 ; hol++){
        $("#plug").append('<td> '+score_arr[gid][hol]+' </td> ');
        console.log(score_arr[gid][hol]);
      total_b[gid]= total_b[gid]+ score_arr[gid][hol];
    }
    $("#plug").append('<td> '+total_b[gid]+' </td> ');

      total[gid]= total_f[gid]+total_f[gid];
      $("#plug").append('<td> '+total[gid]+' </td> ');
    $("#plug").append('</tr> <tr>');
 });
 }

 });


   </script>
```

Dave

Comment: Joe's is fine because you're manually defining it with variables. Bob's might be undefined because of a problem in the MySQL and the `mysql_fetch_array`. Are you sure the array fetching isn't returning an error or returning empty? Then, when the JSON is encoded and it finds out it was undefined, it might just grab the nearest available values.

Comment: Do not use mysql_* it is deprecated. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: can you add the JQuery part too?

Comment: The data in the JSON changes when i change the db value for bob.

Comment: Added the script and jQuery

Comment: plan on converting to mysqli as soon as I get few projects wrapped. How would that affect my issue??

Comment: MrXenotype had it right.  When I manually looked at the output of gse_db_int.php it was fine because I passed it the right variable but it wasn't right when the getJSON sent it.